# Add " to the end of one column in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

How do I add " to the end of every line **in just one column** in notpad++

Eg change

"abc

"abc

"abc

to

"abc"

"abc"

"abc"

Comment: Search  `$` and replace with `"`

Answer (score 1):

This way (click `Replace All`):

[image]

That is, substituting `$` with `"` as a regular expression.